# How to specify width and height for "1fr" in CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a quite complex broken layout which I am trying to achieve with CSS grid, and this the code for my columns and rows layout:

```
grid-template-columns: 8fr 1fr 3fr 8fr 1fr 5fr 2fr 6fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 7fr 1fr 1fr 7fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 4fr 1fr 3fr;
```

Each 1fr here should be 20px, and the rest scaled accordingly, eg. 8fr will be 160px, 3fr will be 60px, and such.

How do I define the width for each column and height for each row, while keeping this exact layout?

Comment: I know the pain. https://twitter.com/keepcoding_/status/724599920221667328

Answer (score 3):

`1fr` is a relative unit. It means take one fraction of what's there to use and use it.

If you want fixed widths you have to define them:

```
grid-template-columns: 100px 20px 40px 100px ....
grid-template-rows: 100px 20px 40px ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
```

the 3 is how many columns you want and the 1fr is the spacing for each of them
you can of course change these numbers which will change the layout and the same applies with `grid-template-rows:repeat (2, 1fr)` etc...

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for CSS variables:

```css
.grid {
  --fr: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: calc(8*var(--fr)) var(--fr) calc(3*var(--fr)) calc(8*var(--fr)) var(--fr) calc(5*var(--fr)) calc(2*var(--fr)) calc(6*var(--fr));
  grid-template-rows: var(--fr) calc(7*var(--fr)) var(--fr) var(--fr) calc(7*var(--fr)) var(--fr) var(--fr) calc(2*var(--fr)) var(--fr) calc(4*var(--fr)) var(--fr) calc(3*var(--fr));
}
```